# Summing the three largest elements in each group in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have been learning pandas dataframes for 2 weeks. At the beginning, everything went well but now I am stuck with the following multi-operation exercise: I have got the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Mountain Range': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 
    'Peak': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's'], 
    'Height above sea level': [2340, 3050, 4220, 2675, 2980, 3300, 3405, 3410, 2970, 2840, 2780, 3140, 3210, 2885, 3000, 3110, 2640, 2635]
    })
```

and  I need to create a function that returns the name ('A', 'B', 'C' or 'D') of the highest mountain range looking only at the three highest peaks present in the mountain ranges. I have tried the combinations of groupby, nlargest, sort_values, sum, but everything failed.

I have tried -

```
df.set_index(['Mountain Range']).nlargest(3, 'Height above sea level').idxmax() 

df.groupby(['Mountain Range'])['Height above sea level'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False) 

df.groupby(['Mountain Range']).nlargest(3, 'Height above sea level).sum()
```

I don't know how to apply nlargest or sum to each group (Mountain range) seperately, not to a whole dataframe

Comment: I don't understand how this is different from getting the mountain range with the highest peak.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough - looking at the three highest peaks means basing on the sum of the height of the three highest peaks.

Comment: Please show what you did. Some of the functions you mentioned are a valid solution, and it's likely you were on the right track

Comment: Also, please make your title specific, like "summing the three largest elements in each group". "Sophisticated" does not apply.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I revised the post title. I have tried:

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I revised the post title. I have tried:
df.set_index(['Mountain Range']).nlargest(3, 'Height above sea level').idxmax()
df.groupby(['Mountain Range'])['Height above sea level'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
df.groupby(['Mountain Range']).nlargest(3, 'Height above sea level).sum()
In general, I don't know how to apply nlargest or sum to each group (Mountain range) seperately, not to a whole dataframe

Comment: Why is this post closed? Question asked by OP is a valid question and he has posted his attempt in the chat instead of adding it to the Question. Flagging for review by mods as this was incorrectly closed for no reason.

Comment: updated OPs question with his attempt

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way:

```
(df.sort_values('Height above sea level', ascending=False)
  .groupby('Mountain Range')['Height above sea level'].nlargest(3)
  .sum(level=0).idxmax())
```

Output:

```
'A'
```

#### How?

- `sort_values` dataframe using height above sea level descending
- `groupby` Mountain Range and get the 3 `nlargest` from each group
- `sum` using `level=0` to sum those values by Mountain Range
- Use `idxmax` to get the index/Mountain Range at with the largest
  summed value

Comment: Thank you @Scott Boston. Your code solved my problem! The first part of it (sort_values, then groupby with pointing out the appropriate column) was the key to the problem. I have checked that when ['Height above sea level'] is missing in the groupby, then the code does not work, which is not fully clear to me. I will greatly appreciate some explanation

Comment: @michael11 I don't understand your question.  If 'height above sea level' is missing, then nlargest has no value to look at for the top three records.  You could fill those missing values with zeros then use the same statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by -

```
g = df.groupby('Mountain Range')['Height above sea level'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(x.nlargest(3))).reset_index()
print(g)
```

```
#get the sum of top 3 peaks heights grouped by Mountain Range
  Mountain Range  Height above sea level
0              A                   10250
1              B                   10115
2              C                    9235
3              D                    8750
```

Next, get the top Mountain range based on height

```
g.nlargest(1, 'Height above sea level')['Mountain Range'][0]
```

```
'A'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as  pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Mountain Range': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 
    'Peak': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's'], 
    'Height above sea level': [2340, 3050, 4220, 2675, 2980, 3300, 3405, 3410, 2970, 2840, 2780, 3140, 3210, 2885, 3000, 3110, 2640, 2635]
    })

df = df.sort_values(by=['Height above sea level'])
print(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Mountain Range'], keep='last'))
```

## OUTPUT

```
Mountain Range Peak  Height above sea level
15              D    p                    3110
12              C    m                    3210
7               B    h                    3410
2               A    c                    4220
```